# Openstack installation by using KAYOBE fails at Keystone database creation step

Tags: openstack

I try since few days to install Openstack (all-in-one) by using KAYOBE.
I follow all configuration steps described here https://docs.openstack.org/kayobe/latest/installation.html and here https://docs.openstack.org/kayobe/latest/configuration/scenarios/all-in-one/overcloud.html#configuration

Everything goes well until to the deployment of containers at step [Creating keystone database]

I get the following error:

```
TASK [Creating keystone database] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/myuser/KayobeFromSource-VICTORIA-000/venvs/kolla-ansible/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/keystone/tasks/bootstrap.yml:2
<192.168.213.36> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kolla
<192.168.213.36> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kolla"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/bd8f57e3b9 192.168.213.36 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~kolla && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.213.36> (0, b'/home/kolla\n', b'')
<192.168.213.36> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kolla
<192.168.213.36> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kolla"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/bd8f57e3b9 192.168.213.36 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826="` echo /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.213.36> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826=/home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826\n', b'')
Using module file /home/myuser/KayobeFromSource-VICTORIA-000/venvs/kolla-ansible/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/library/kolla_toolbox.py
<192.168.213.36> PUT /home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-34087ubr5ng1m/tmpm3v5h_xa TO /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826/AnsiballZ_kolla_toolbox.py
<192.168.213.36> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kolla"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/bd8f57e3b9 '[192.168.213.36]'
<192.168.213.36> (0, b'sftp> put /home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-34087ubr5ng1m/tmpm3v5h_xa /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826/AnsiballZ_kolla_toolbox.py\n', b'')
<192.168.213.36> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kolla
<192.168.213.36> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kolla"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/bd8f57e3b9 192.168.213.36 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826/ /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826/AnsiballZ_kolla_toolbox.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.213.36> (0, b'', b'')
<192.168.213.36> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kolla
<192.168.213.36> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kolla"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/bd8f57e3b9 -tt 192.168.213.36 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-tbgufwaydrmyknjdvkvrkovocfzsrwaz ; /opt/kayobe/venvs/kolla-ansible/bin/python /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826/AnsiballZ_kolla_toolbox.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<192.168.213.36> (0, b'\r\n{"action": "mysql_db", "changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"ca_cert": null, "client_cert": null, "client_key": null, "collation": "", "config_file": "/var/lib/ansible/.my.cnf", "connect_timeout": 30, "encoding": "", "ignore_tables": [], "login_host": "192.168.213.100", "login_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", "login_port": 3306, "login_unix_socket": null, "login_user": "root", "name": ["keystone"], "quick": true, "single_transaction": false, "state": "present", "target": null}}, "msg": "unable to find /var/lib/ansible/.my.cnf. Exception message: (1045, \\"Access denied for user \'root\'@\'controller0\' (using password: YES)\\")"}\r\n', b'Shared connection to 192.168.213.36 closed.\r\n')
<192.168.213.36> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kolla
<192.168.213.36> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kolla"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/bd8f57e3b9 192.168.213.36 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/kolla/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610524125.732474-54781-193202051714826/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.213.36> (0, b'', b'')
fatal: [controller0 -> 192.168.213.36]: FAILED! => {
    "action": "mysql_db",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "collation": "",
            "config_file": "/var/lib/ansible/.my.cnf",
            "connect_timeout": 30,
            "encoding": "",
            "ignore_tables": [],
            "login_host": "192.168.213.100",
            "login_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "login_port": 3306,
            "login_unix_socket": null,
            "login_user": "root",
            "name": [
                "keystone"
            ],
            "quick": true,
            "single_transaction": false,
            "state": "present",
            "target": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "unable to find /var/lib/ansible/.my.cnf. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'controller0' (using password: YES)\")"
```

For information, I am using VMWare Workstation 16 with a VM with CentOS 8.

I tried to Google and find possible fixes but without success.

Any idea and help will be much appreciated !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found. The issue was that I tried several times to install openstack and each time I deleted files and docker images. but I never deleted docker volumes. When I deleted them and reinstall openStack with Kayobe, everything worked fine.